# Add class using jquery to a determinate HTML structure pattern

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following structure in HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">3</a>    <!-- Add class to this a -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">5</a>    <!-- Add class to this a -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5.1</a>     <!-- Add class to this a -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">5.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I would like to add a class using jQuery to the 'a' elements where there is an 'a' with a 'ul' So, Add a class to all 'a' elements which have the following pattern:

```
li > a, ul
```

-

```
<li>
    <a href="#"></a>        <!-- Add class to this a -->
    <ul>
        ....
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have tried severals ways but I can not get it:

For example:

```
$('ul li a ul').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).has('a, ul') ) {
      $(this).addClass('myClass');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single line by retrieving all the nested `ul` elements and using `prev()` to get the previous `a`:

```
$('li > ul').prev('a').addClass('foo');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bhvphmn6/)

Comment: Thank you soo much!! Yep it's much better a single line :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` to find the `ul li a` elements which have a `ul` sibling:

```js
$('ul li a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).siblings('ul').length>0;  
}).addClass("hasUL");
```

```css
.hasUL{
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">3</a>    <!-- Add class to this a -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">5</a>    <!-- Add class to this a -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5.1</a>     <!-- Add class to this a -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">5.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('ul li').find('ul').siblings('a').addClass('addClass');
```

```css
.addClass{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">3</a>    <!-- Add class to this a -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3.3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">5</a>    <!-- Add class to this a -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5.1</a>     <!-- Add class to this a -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">5.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

1. Find UL in the list and get the sibling a to add the class

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function(k, v) {
    if ($(v).next().is('ul')) {
      $(v).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">3</a> 
    <!-- Add class to this a -->
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">3.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">3.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">3.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">5</a> 
    <!-- Add class to this a -->
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">5.1</a> 
        <!-- Add class to this a -->
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">5.1.1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">5.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```